# Book library management solutions, that allows adding titles with a upc reader?

Tags: applications, barcode

What would be a good easy way to catalog my physical book library with a UPC reader on android? Would you have suggestions for a simple individual library management solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this application [Book Catalogue](http://www.appbrain.com/app/book-catalogue/com.eleybourn.bookcatalogue)

Answer (score 2):

[Goodreads](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.goodreads) has an app for this that works with their website, which includes book reviews and recommendations as well.

You can sort books by shelves, which can correspond to physical shelves if you choose (e.g. living room, bedroom, lent out to a friend).